# Controller inside a controller... maybe I'm wrong

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a "standard" page layout.

A header, a footer, a main block of content on the left hand side and a sidebar on the right hand side.

Now this is all well and good, except the sidebar is replicated in each and every controller, but needs a controller to function. Sometimes the user might be logged in and therefore there will be some working out of name and such there. Also there is going to be a shopping cart there which will run from a MySQL database.

I don't want to replicate this code in each of my controllers.

How would I make a controller that will build the sidebar, load the view and everything that I can then "include" (like I would include a view) into the page.

I can forsee the creation of a `sidebar` class/object which I could instantiate and "add to the view" as it were.

How am I supposed to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually created a library which did the stuff I needed. This works well. Libraries can be made effectively like simple controllers and included into them anywhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Modular Extensions-HMVC](https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home) might be a good solution for you. The wiki I linked includes examples.

Comment: That looks interesting, thank you. But don't tell me that codeigniter doesn't have a native solution to this! :p Its one of the most famous frameworks out there and it can't handle cross-controller code?

Comment: Well, you could create a MY_Controller that builds the sidebar and then extend that with the rest of your controllers, but I think that HMVC will be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

When I've had this issue in Codeigniter in the past I've built a hook that loads post_controller_constructor, executes some logic and then loads a sidebar.php view. It's fairly simple and doesn't require all that much effort.

The only issue is that if you're not using templating then it may mess with the order in which you call views. For example if you're used to:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view("header.php");
    $this->load->view("my_awesome_page.php", $this->data);
    $this->load->view("footer.php");
}
```

Then you'll have to alter it to be aware that the sidebar will be the last thing called and put the footer in there. Usually I'll have the Hook check the CI Object for a variable to see if there's a sidebar required and then if not just spit out footer.php anyway.

I'm fairly confident [hooks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html) are what you're looking for though.